# Using meteor in chrome extension

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to take for example the todos app (from the meteor examples ) and load it as a chrome extension?
Meaning the extension will display the list of the todos on my meteor web app?

Comment: There are Chrome apps, and Chrome extensions. I don't think you mean extension, since extensions are for modifying/adding browser functionality. For apps, there are packaged apps and hosted. Packaged run locally on users machine, and hosted run on a server. The hosted app just links to the server and you have a normal browser experience, as with any web app. Hosted is easy, packaged would be a challenge I think, since Meteor uses node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the webpage with the extension, yes.

If you wanted to do something more native, you would have to import the data somehow. You could create a page that outputs JSON for the todo list, and process that from within the extension.

Comment: Loading the webpage meaning calling it from an iframe? if not could you explain what you mean? and importing the data mean I will have to export it somehow as well and that means I have to build some kind of a wrapper for the whole communication with my app - it kind of losing what meteor is all about...